# Shared axis polar subplots using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, axis, radial

I'm plotting different Scatterpolar charts using subplots. Yet I want them to all have the same range [0,1]. I've tried using radialaxis and update_layout. However only the first of the subplots changes. Is there a way I can modify all subplots?

```
lst = range(1,rows+1)
n_rows = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, cols) for x in lst))

df_grouped = df.groupby('cluster').mean()
fig = make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=cols, specs=[[{'type': 'polar'}]*cols]*rows,
                    horizontal_spacing=0.05, vertical_spacing=0.06)

for col, (row, index) in enumerate(zip(n_rows, df_grouped.index.values)):
      fig.add_trace( go.Scatterpolar(name="Cluster "+str(int(index)),
                                     r=df_grouped.loc[df_grouped.index == index].values[0],
                                     theta=df_grouped.columns.values),
                    row, col%cols+1)

fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.update_layout(polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(range=[0, 1])),
                  legend=dict(x=0.20,y=1.15), legend_orientation="h",
                  height=800, width=900, 
                  margin=dict(l=5, r=5, t=5, b=5)                    )

p = plot(fig, output_type='div')

displayHTML(p)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: each polar subplot has its own key in `layout` so you’ll want to do something like `update_layout(polar=dict(...), polar2=dict(...), polar3=dict(...), ...)`

We don’t yet have a single function to batch update all `polar`s like we do for `update_xaxes` but we will soon :)